How to stop particles from restarting when rendering in parts
I've noticed that it I have animation thats for example frames 0-250 and I render 0-100 and then save and quit and come back and set the render animation length from 101-250 and hit render aall the particles misbehave, restarting their animations now from 101st frame messing up the animation. How do I stop that from happening. Do I just bake particles or is there a better way?

This question is similar to: How do I save (bake) a particle simulation?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. The UI on this question is old, but it's basically the same for newer blender versions

I know how to bake but I want to know if baking is the only way to achieve this so I don't have to re-bake every time I make a correction and re-render the project since I do that a lot.

By definition, baking is the fact to save the simulation in some folder so that it can be accessed later. If you want the changes to remain after closing your file, then you should definitively bake it.
